# How to download a dataset using java

Tags: java, dataset

I want to make an app that will download all the paper mentioned in the image by taking the domain as input. i have been able to download a single file from some other website but was unable to download a paper form acm digital library.
what i need to do is download the entire data set.

here is the code that i used to download a single file.

```
     String fileName = "1.txt"; 
     URL link = new URL("http://shayconcepts.com"); 
     InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(link.openStream());
     ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     byte[] buf = new byte[2048];
     int n = 0;
     while (-1!=(n=in.read(buf)))
     {
        out.write(buf, 0, n);
     }
     out.close();
     in.close();
     byte[] response = out.toByteArray();

     FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
     fos.write(response);

     fos.close();
```

How can I modify it to download entire data set

Comment: no one has answer to my question :(